# How To Style Form Input Fields With Inline Background Color Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a form in which I would like to style the input fields with a particular background color, when I click inside the form. However, I having a little trouble with this. Here is what I have:

```html
<form name="" action="/communicate/#wpcf7-f11-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="11" /><br />       
  <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.0" /><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="" /><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f11-o1" /><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="d6b53e1ecd" />      
</div>
<p style="color: #fff;">Your Name (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
</p>
<p style="color: #fff;">Your Email (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
</p>
<p style="color: #fff;">Subject<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
</p>
<p style="color: #fff;">Your Message<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

I want to style the input field to be Black on selection. There's also an overlay style I want, but I'll deal with that later. Can anyone help with this? I don't have the luxury of writing a CSS rule, because I'm hacking together a broken form from someone's wacky WordPress site.  Wouldn't the change be done in the `<span>` tag? I styled the field names inline with `#fff`, and would like to do the inputs with `#000`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
     background: black;
     color: white;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can add the following code inside your `<input>` tags and the `<textarea>` tag:

```
onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'"
```

like this:

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false">
```

---

```html
    <form name="" action="/communicate/#wpcf7-f11-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="11" /><br />       
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.0" /><br />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="" /><br />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f11-o1" /><br />
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="d6b53e1ecd" />      
    </div>
    <p style="color: #fff;">Your Name (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'" type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    </p>
    <p style="color: #fff;">Your Email (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'" type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    </p>
    <p style="color: #fff;">Subject<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'" type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    </p>
    <p style="color: #fff;">Your Message<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black';this.style.color='white'" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='white';this.style.color='black'" name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Again... I do not have the liberty to write a rule to the CSS... I have to do it **Inline**.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that by adding the CSS inline since pseudo-selectors like `:focus` cannot be used as inline CSS. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: No, and this sucks, because it's for a WordPress Contact Form 7... I can't locate the controlling stylesheet for it! :(

Comment: You don't need to specifically edit the stylesheet of the Contact Form 7 plugin in order to bring about this change, you can also add this code in your main stylesheet along with `!important`. Nevertheless, the most that you can do with inline CSS, which I guess you'd already know, is change the `background-color` of the `input` field and the `textarea`.

Comment: Yes, Fahad, you are correct. Can you assist what I would need to produce the Black background `onLoad` and `onclick` with the text appearing as White?

Comment: So far I see this works: `onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='black'"` but I can't get the `onLoad` nor the White text to show within the black input.

Comment: @designermind Please check my updated answer above and run the snippet to test it. This works perfectly as per your needs and I've achieved it only using inline JS.

Comment: Awesome. Any way to do an inline so it loads black to begin with? You've earned the credit on this one. I'll set it with the code you've provided,  but just want the input box to be black when the page loads. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63281/discussion-between-designermind-and-fahad-hasan).

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the css outline property if you want to change the outline.

```
input:focus, textarea:focus{
 outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;
```

}

Comment: You all are not reading into the question... I **have to do it Inline** if possible. I cannot write a rule in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Sorry. Inspecting the element with your browser should help you locate the stylesheet that styles it or if the worst came to the worst you could email the plugin admin.

Comment: He can't use Jquery Parody, What abut pure javascript Designermind ? Something along the lines of onclick setting the style and then an onclick on the body resetting them all. Or a js function in the Head ?

Comment: '<input onclick="this.style.outline='#00FF00 dotted thick',this.style.backgroundColor='black'" onblur="this.style='backgroundColor='white',this.style.border=''"/>'

Comment: Was this what you used as a direct inline style, Billy? And it made the change?

Comment: @billy i didnt see that but i have now just added a pure javascript way.

Comment: The onblur isn't working for some reason, still fiddling

Comment: Hey guys, I see that the change completed, but it made a new input block. Check this out: http://www.scratchandholler.com/section-fixed, then scroll down. Click inside one of the inputs. This is what I'm trying to achieve on an existing one.

Comment: Parody, Can't comment on your answer due to low rep. Didn't even know about onfocus and focusout, Thanks for them.. is focusout working for you ? ~Can't get it or the blur to work ?? Maybe a browser issue. ## EDIT ## Just cleared cache and it's working now. Nice one Parody

Comment: @Billy what would the line for onload look like? I would like to have it black onload, as I plan to overlay a screen on it, show when I click, you still the black.

Comment: Hello... I'd like to shoot someone some credit here. Anyway to set in an `onload` for the input as well?

Comment: You can't put the onload on an input or form, just tried it. if you just do an inline style so it loads black then do whatever on the focus() function to over write it. Or is it the whole body you want black ?

Answer (score 0):

I ready that your not able to write to the css file so you could use jquery like this

```
$(":input").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background","green");

    $(this).focusout(function(){
        $(this).css("background","");
     });
});
```

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/9oao4p89/1/) showing it in action

**EDIT** after seeing billy post that you cant use jquery here is a simple javascript function that does it.

```
<input type="text" id="demoinput" onfocus="demoFocus(this.id)" onfocusout="demoFocusout(this.id)">

<script>
function demoFocus(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = "yellow";
}
function demoFocusout(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = "";
} 
</script>
```

and a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/cgpnbxrL/1/) of this way